Data series not displaying correctly in a scatter plot in Excel
Original post below - updating starting a new chart from scratch with issue narrowed down.
Trying to create a "Stakeholder Matrix" as a scatter plot diagram.  (Good overview article here).
Basic data entered as image below shows, and the scatter chart plots out with no issues:
Data
"Good" scatter chart
Since I'd like to separate Advocates from Neutrals (Follower + Neutral) from Blockers (Blocker + Opponents), I'm trying to create three separate data series that can be plotted and color coded to indicate where each person categorizes.
The initial challenge was all I was doing was a simple IF statement to populate the new data series based on the value in column D.  That meant gaps in the data and as such would plot the data as a 0 for each gap.  I tried null and N/A with the setting on the series to display as gaps to no avail.
So did some searching and found an article on how to generate a column of data from an original column based on a condition with not data gaps (using a helper column - I got the suggestion from CoPilot but this article is virtually the same).
So now, my data table looks like this:
enter image description here
As you can see, using the helper column keying on "Advocate", I'm able to generate columns G and H as an Advocate series with no gaps.
HOWEVER, plotting this data series, results in the following graph:
enter image description here.  What's happening is the Y axis gets plotted per the data, but the X axis value is plotting as the data sequence number (e.g. 1, 2, 3.)  I can see the data series is defined correctly, but displaying values from the chart data table:
enter image description here.
Really at a loss here on how to get these data pairs to plot correctly.  FYI - I have verified all the cells with numbers have the Number format.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Original Post:
I'm creating a scatter plot, tracking three data series.  Each series is a data pair of two columns next to each other.  The data in each cell is computed, with a formula similar to:
=IF($D8=$H$6, $E8, "")

Everything displays fine in the cells, but when I plot the series plots wrong in two ways:

X and Y values are not what are in the cell.
One of the cells (the Y value) is somehow getting filled with zeros. The X values are fine (showing the blanks) and all I did is copy the formula above from the X column to the Y column.

On item one - here's an example.  X and Y values in a row are 9 and 8 respectively.  On the chart, they are getting plotted as 1 and 8.  I even turned data labels on to display the X and Y values.  The data point is clearly indicating the values to be 9 and 8, yet the data point is plotting at 1 and 8.
I'm at my wits end. I've triple checked the data series ranges - all good. I've traced back to the source data to make sure cell formats are numeric and not off - all good. When I right click on one of the data points and go to Edit Series, the only real option is whether to plot on the primary or secondary axis - no impact.
Why is one column's formula filling in blanks where the column right next to it with the same formula is inserting 0s?  Why are the source X and Y value display correctly, but the data point is plotting incorrectly?

You can upload images to https://imgur.com and link to them, someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you. Including some sample data (ideally in a markdown table ) would also be useful

It's best share us a screenshot and the data source.

Images included, including a screenshot of the data table.

In a scatter chart, all x-axis data must be numbers. If there is at least one text value, in this case, for example, empty text, the entire axis is treated as an axis with text values, which are numbered consecutively from 1 to the number of points. On the other hand, if there is text among the y-axis data, it is treated as a 0 value.
So you need to eliminate the texts from your x-axis data.

Update
Your x-range includes cells G2:G30. Only G2:G4 contain numbers, further cells contain blank texts, which are the cause of the problem. If you have 3 data points, use a 3-point range, i.e. G2:G4, or use a named formula to calculate this range.
But it will probably be easier to remove the contents from cells G5:G30 so that they are empty.
If the cell contains text, numeric formatting won't help.

Please see updated comments above.  Reworked the entire data table - there are no text values nor gaps in the data. Still not charting correctly.
